# Quick ways to compute transition matrices for classical symmetric function bases

Tags: reference-request, symmetric-functions, recurrences, computation

I am trying to implement quick algorithms for computing the transition matrices
involving the monomial, power-sum, elementary, complete homogeneous and Schur polynomials.

There are several relations among these, and all have [combinatorial interpretations](https://www.math.upenn.edu/%7Epeal/polynomials/standardSymmetricFunctions.htm#symmetricTransisionMatrices).
The matrix for expanding the $h_\lambda$ into $s_\mu$, given by inverse Kostka coefficients,
can be computed quickly using a recursion, due to  Eğecioğlu and Remmel.

From here, one only needs one of the matrices for
$e_\lambda \to p_\mu$, $h_\lambda \to  p_\mu$, $s_\lambda \to  p_\mu$ or
$m_\lambda \to  p_\mu$, (or the inverse). The remaining transition matrices are obtained via simple matrix operations.

There is a recursion for augmented monomials to power-sums, see [M. Merca](https://springerplus.springeropen.com/articles/10.1186/s40064-015-1506-5),
which I implemented, but was surprised that it is quite a bit slower compared to the Eğecioğlu and Remmel recursion above. This is surprising, as Schur polynomials seem much more complicated compared to the other bases.

**Are more efficient recursions out there, for the coefficients of the transition matrices
$e_\lambda \to p_\mu$, $h_\lambda \to  p_\mu$, $s_\lambda \to  p_\mu$ or
$m_\lambda \to  p_\mu$?**

I have also looked into source code for Symmetrica (do not read C-code commented in German that well), and Stembridges SF package (which uses a method that is slower than M. Merca's approach).

*Eğecioğlu, Ömer; Remmel, Jeffrey B.*, [**A combinatorial interpretation of the inverse Kostka matrix**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1080/03081089008817966), Linear Multilinear Algebra 26, No. 1-2, 59-84 (1990). [ZBL0735.05013](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0735.05013).

Comment: Did you look into how it is implemented in SAGE?

Comment: @DanPetersen I believe Sage uses Symmetrica under the hood, see https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/libs/sage/libs/symmetrica/symmetrica.html
And yeah, the Symmetrica source code is not super readable...

Comment: @DanPetersen I realized that even though Schur polynomials are more complicated, perhaps it is worth computing the p->s coefficients (characters), as these are so important. I found a preprint by R. Holmes, with a very nice recursion: https://www.math.upenn.edu/~peal/polynomials/murnaghanNakayama.htm#holmesChi
It should be quicker than the naive recursion given by the Murnaghan-Nakayama rule.